# Why can a windows targeted docker image run as a Linux Web App in azure?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I may not understand docker completely, and I guess that's why I'm making this post. To my understanding a linux container basically runs on a linux kernel, where the windows one runs on windows.

I have the following setup:

```
*.csproj
<DockerDefaultTargetOS>Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-nanoserver-1809 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-nanoserver-1809 AS build
WORKDIR /src
...
...
```

So basically it pulls the `Windows` images. Everything builds and works locally (in fact I can't get it to run with Linux because of permission problems, which is why I opted for Windows in the first place).

The app is a .NET Core 2.2 WebApp.

Then I wanted to setup my CI/CD pipeline in Azure Devops. Build:

```
pool:
  name: Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019
steps:
- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'Build an image'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MySubscription'
    azureContainerRegistry: 'myRegistry'
    dockerFile: API/Dockerfile
    defaultContext: False
    context: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    imageName: 'reg/name:$(Build.BuildId)'

- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'Push an image'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Subscription'
    azureContainerRegistry: 'myContainerRegistry'
    action: 'Push an image'
    imageName: 'reg/name:$(Build.BuildId)'
```

And publish:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'Push an image'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MySubscription'
    azureContainerRegistry: 'registry'
    action: 'Push an image'
    imageName: 'reg/name:$(Build.BuildId)'
```

Then the odd part I have no clue why works. I wanted to release it, and figuring it was a windows image, it would have to be a WebApp from this list:

[image: App type selection list]

It couldn't find the image, so after some fiddling I tried simply changing it to the `Linux Web App`, which has fields for actually finding the correct image (out of the box), adding it to the container registry and so on - and it just worked. It seemed very much like the WebApp config is classic zip deployment, where as Linux Web App is actually more a "Docker App" configuration.

I'm just trying to understand why this works, and if I've grossly misunderstood what Docker actually does. Does it simply not matter what the container type is, as long as the app is cross platform like .net core?